# How to use a for loop to create new dataframes on each iteration of the loop?

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, each iteration of the for loop is fed into the "sector" dataframe, which uses boolean indexing, and the results are exported to excel.
"ia sectors" is a list comprising string values e.g. healthcare, consumer_staples, property etc.

```
for item in ia_sectors:
 sector = all_data[all_data["IA Sector"] == item]
 sector.to_excel(str(item)+".xlsx")
```

Is it possible to modify the code such that each iteration of the for loop creates a new dataframe with the iterative names in item and their respective iterative results from the boolean indexing? e.g.

```
for item in ia_sectors:
 item0 = all_data[all_data["IA Sector"] == item0]
 sector.to_excel(str(item0)+".xlsx")
 item1 = all_data[all_data["IA Sector"] == item1]
 sector.to_excel(str(item1)+".xlsx")
 item2 = all_data[all_data["IA Sector"] == item2]
 sector.to_excel(str(item2)+".xlsx")
```

I would like to work with these new dataframes later on in the code.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

```
dd = {}
ia_sector_data = all_data[all_date['IA Sector'].isin(ia_sectors)]

for n, g in ia_sector_data.groupby('IA Sector'):
    dd[n] = g
    g.to_excel(f'{n}.xls')
```

Now, your dataframes are accessible in a dictionary, dd.

Using dd['Sec1'] and so on.

Comment: Thank you for this and apologies it took me so long to respond.